# JPA mapping for one-to-many collection of shared data, with user specific values

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a User model that contains a list of achievements

```
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.achievements",
        attributeNodes={
                @NamedAttributeNode("achievements")
        })

@Data
public class User {
 @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetClass = Achievement.class)
private List<Achievement> achievements = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Here's the achievement model

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "achievement")
public class Achievement {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
private String achievementId;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "achieved", columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT false", nullable = false)
private boolean achieved = false;
```

`user_achievements` table generated from @ElementCollection mapping, which atm only contains user and achievement foreign keys

[image]

I am looking to move the `boolean achieved` value to the `user_achievements` table,  ideally without having to create a separate model User_Achievements

I am fairly new to using Jpa, but i feel like this scenario is too basic so there must be a straight forward way to do that i cant seem to locate it

Comment: `@ElementCollection `can only be used with basic types like `String`, `Integer` or `Enum`'s: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html. You should use a `@...ToMany` association.

Comment: good point, but i am able to pass my object in targetclass and it works, is it bad practice just due to cascade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Entity
class UserAchievement {

  @EmbeddableId
  UserAchievementId id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="user_username", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  User user;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="achivement_achivement_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  Achivement achivement;

  // and other fields
}

class User {

  // ...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
  List<UserAchievement> userAchievements;
}
```

and you need to define `UserAchievementId`

Comment: i already have an achievement table, but the column values will be shared across users as per above specification. am looking for a way to store unique values such as `boolean completed` which should be stored in a table user_achievement

Comment: so, AFAIK, you must use `@ManyToMany`. and  we need `user_achievement ` 
 table's detail

Comment: i already have user_achievements table create from the `@ElementCollection` in user model, but atm it only stores `user_username` and `achievements_achievement_id` as foreign keys. I am looking to have more values stores in this table, but not sure how to specify it in JPA

Comment: Thanks yuki, i've decided to go with a similar solution to the above. 
I was trying to avoid  having to create `UserAchievement` model, but there doesn't seem to be a more straight forward JPA solution.